# How to run command from within eclipse(Pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse, postgresql

Is it possible to run  python command from within eclipse(Pydev)?

I want to create a procedure which will create database. Currently I create database by writing the command in command prompt, But I want the same from my code within eclipse.

Something like:

```
def createDatabase()
     createdb -U myUser -T template0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [popen2](http://docs.python.org/library/popen2.html) module. It allows you to spawn processes. Then you can call your function from PyDev console

Comment: ``popen2`` is deprecated. The correct module to use is ``subprocess``: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute a program from Run>External Tools>External Tools Configurations.  Once you set it up, you can re-run it from the toolbar.